# 'CommentHelper' is not iterable

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to learn how to make a Reddit bot in Python but am getting the following error message...

```
C:\Users\Warbz\Desktop>python redditbot.py
Logging in...
Grabbing subreddit...
Grabbing comments...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redditbot.py", line 30, in <module>
    run_bot()
  File "redditbot.py", line 19, in run_bot
    for comment in subredditComments:
TypeError: 'CommentHelper' object is not iterable
```

My code is this...

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(client_id="***",
            client_secret="***",
            username="***",
            password="***",
            user_agent = "/u/Fazy89")#Description of the script

print("Logging in...")

words_to_match = ['definately', 'defiantly', 'definantly', 'definatly', 'definitly']
cache = []#ID's of comments already replied to

def run_bot():
    print("Grabbing subreddit...")
    subreddit = r.subreddit("test")#Get SubReddit e.g /r/test
    print("Grabbing comments...")
    subredditComments = subreddit.comments
    for comment in subredditComments:
        comment_text = comment.body.lower()#Assign variable to lower case body of text 
        isMatch = any(string in comment_text for string in words_to_match)
        if comment.id not in cache and isMatch:#^If comment has not been added to cache and is a match
            print("Match found! Comment ID: " +comment.id)
            comment.reply('I think you meant to say "Definitely".')
            print("Reply successful!")
            cache.append(comment.id)#Add comment ID to cache
    print("Comments loop finished, going to sleep...")

while True:
    run_bot()
    time.sleep(10)
```

I've tried looking at the PRAW api but I'm not sure what is actually going wrong, any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comments` provides an instance of CommentHelper, which needs to be instantiated using parenthesis to call it.

```
for comment in r.subreddit('test').comments(limit=25):
    print(comment.author)
```

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.comments

Comment: I still get this error after adding your code, comment was too long so I've just included the end section, hopefully it's enough info...



     File "C:\Users\Warbz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 328, in refresh
    password=self._password)
      File "C:\Users\Warbz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 142, in _request_token
    payload.get('error_description'))
    prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request

Comment: Please read the actual error. That is a different one from the initial post. OAuth would be something wrong with the password/key you provided

Comment: Okay so I just figured out only the reddit account you used to create the OAuth credentials can use the client sercret and ID, thank you!